# Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered when I started using firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native

My errors are:

```
Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder.

ReferenceError: Property 'initializeApp' doesn't exist, js engine: hermes
```

Here is my AppeEntry.js file which is like the index.js file:

```
import registerRootComponent from 'expo/build/launch/registerRootComponent';

import App from '../../App';

registerRootComponent(App);
```

Now here is the database/firebase file:

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyDtHTodTxYPLVHzy8GRVLAFWLPxCwHDGdA",
  authDomain: "calendar-app-2baab.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "calendar-app-2baab",
  storageBucket: "calendar-app-2baab.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "257098776368",
  appId: "1:257098776368:web:40acf9bd1df66a8df392f5",
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = firebase.firestore();

export default {
  firebase,
  db,
};
```

I ask this because the duplicate answer did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this error is related to how you're importing firebase library.

Taking a look into [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase#use-firebase-in-your-app), the example shows this:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
```

Instead of:

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app"
```

As you're using `react-native` I would suggest you to use this [`@react-native-firebase`](https://rnfirebase.io/) package instead.

Comment: still getting the error referenceError: Property 'firebase' doesn't exist, js engine: hermes and Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered.

Comment: Have you installed `firebase` package? Try running `npm i firebase` or `yarn add firebase` then try again